# Entity Framework Core Class Library build giving error CS7036

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm sure there's something small and dumb that I'm missing here. When I attempt to build my class library I get the following error:

```
StaticDataHelper.cs(13,16): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required form
al parameter 'options' of 'StaticDataContext.StaticDataContext(DbContextOptions<StaticDataContext>)' [C:\U
sers\bryce\Google Drive\dotnet\libraries\EveStaticData\EveStaticData.csproj]
```

The relevant code block looks like this:

```
public StaticDataContext(DbContextOptions<StaticDataContext> options)
    :base(options)
{  }
```

I was attempting to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) guide Microsoft put out.

I've created a GitHub repository of my code [here](https://github.com/drbryce/eve-static-data-lib) and the specific file in question is [here.](https://github.com/drbryce/eve-static-data-lib/blob/master/Model/Static%20Data/StaticDataContext.cs)

I've checked over the constructor function again and again and all other similar guides/tutorials used the same code.

I'm using:

- EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.2
- .netcore 1.1

Let me know if there's any other info that could help.

Comment: Have you tried to use IOptions<T> instead of DbContextOptions<T> ?

Comment: @eiton Has my answer resolved your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to pass `DbContextOptions` to both the constructor and to the `OnConfiguring()` method. Just do it in either the `ctor` or the `OnConfiguring()` method.

> If both are used, OnConfiguring is executed on the supplied options,
>   meaning it is additive and can overwrite options supplied to the
>   constructor argument.+

See here for guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Sample code change that should resolve your issue (if you are not injecting the DBContextOptions from the `Startup`:

```
public partial class StaticDataContext : DbContext
{
    public StaticDataContext()  {   }

    //...

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Datasource=sqlite-latest.sqlite");
    }

    //...
}
```

If you are injecting the `DbContextOptions` via dependency injection, then use the following:

```
public partial class StaticDataContext : DbContext
{
    public StaticDataContext(DbContextOptions<StaticDataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    //...

    //Removed as it's being injected in to the ctor via DI
    //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    //{
    //  optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Datasource=sqlite-latest.sqlite");
    //}

    //...
}
```